# How to freely traverse the elements in a two-dimensional array by cardinal direction? (DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22239871/2736496) is about figuring the path through a maze, as is represented by a two-dimensional array. For example, the path through this maze

```
   0 1 2 3 4
   ---------
0| 1 0 1 1 1
1| 1 0 0 0 1
2| 1 0 1 0 1
3| 1 1 1 0 1
4| 1 1 1 0 1
```

is

```
START: [0,1]
Down:  [1,1]
Right: [1,2]
Right: [1,3]
Down:  [2,3]
Down:  [3,3]
Down:  [4,3]
```

The poster was attempting to do this purely with recursion, and actually posted four different questions about it within five hours--which speaks to its complexity.

This got me thinking of the more generic question: How do you freely move around the elements in a two-dimensional array, in any cardinal direction? DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT

If this problem can be solved, then traversing a maze would be much easier.

Comment: I also want to share this alternative answer to the maze question, which is a really interesting take on recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22242301/2736496

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with two classes, and an Enum.

First, the enum, which defines the direction you want to move and determines the new indexes, one-at-a-time, based on its movement.

```
enum Direction {
   UP(-1, 0),
   DOWN(1, 0),
   LEFT(0, -1),
   RIGHT(0, 1);

   private final int rowSteps;
   private final int colSteps;
   private Direction(int rowSteps, int colSteps)  {
      this.rowSteps = rowSteps;
      this.colSteps = colSteps;
   }
   public int getNewRowIdx(int currentRowIdx)  {
      return  (currentRowIdx + getRowSteps());
   }
   public int getNewColIdx(int currentColIdx)  {
      return  (currentColIdx + getColSteps());
   }
   public int getRowSteps()  {
      return  rowSteps;
   }
   public int getColSteps()  {
      return  colSteps;
   }
};
```

The main class is called `GridPosition` (below). First you set the double-array grid into it, via its `int[][]` constructor, and store that instance statically:

```
private static final GridPosition GRID_HOLDER = new GridPosition(GRID);
```

(This step could be designed better, but it works. Also, it should accept any type.)

After setting the grid (which is a one-time-only thing, per-execution), then the x/y constructor is used to declare an initial position:

```
GridPosition pos = new GridPosition(0, 0);
```

And after that, just move as necessary:

```
pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
...
```

The value of each position is retrieved by `pos.getValue()`. (As an aside: The huge 2d-array used for the maze--at the bottom of this post, in the "full code"--should really contain one-bit `booleans`, instead of 4-byte `ints`, but *looking* at the array's code makes sense with `int`s, and doesn't with booleans... Note that it should at least be changed to `byte`s.)

So regarding movement, if you attempt to get a neighbor when there is none, such as moving left at the left edge, an `IllegalStateException` is thrown. Use the `is*Edge()` functions to avoid this.

The GridPosition class also has a convenient debugging function called `getNineByNine()`, which returns a 9x9 grid of the array values (as a string), where the middle item is the current position.

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
   import  java.util.Objects;
class GridPosition  {
//state
   private static int[][] GRID;
   private final int rowIdx;
   private final int colIdx;
//internal
   private final int rowIdxMinus1;
   private final int colIdxMinus1;
   public GridPosition(int[][] GRID)  {
      if(this.GRID != null)  {
         throw  new IllegalStateException("Grid already set. Use x/y constructor.");
      }
      GridPosition.GRID = GRID;

      //TODO: Crash if null or empty, or sub-arrays null or empty, or unequal lengths, or contain anything but 0 or -1.

      rowIdx = -1;
      colIdx = -1;
      rowIdxMinus1 = -1;
      colIdxMinus1 = -1;
   }
   public GridPosition(int rowIdx, int colIdx)  {
      if(GridPosition.GRID == null)  {
         throw  new IllegalStateException("Must set grid with: new GridPosition(int[][]).");
      }

      if(rowIdx < 0  ||  rowIdx >= GridPosition.getRowCount())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("rowIdx (" + rowIdx + ") is invalid.");
      }
      if(colIdx < 0  ||  colIdx >= GridPosition.getColumnCount())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("colIdx (" + colIdx + ") is invalid.");
      }

      this.rowIdx = rowIdx;
      this.colIdx = colIdx;
      rowIdxMinus1 = (rowIdx - 1);
      colIdxMinus1 = (colIdx - 1);
   }
   public int getValue()  {
      return  GridPosition.GRID[getRowIdx()][getColumnIdx()];
   }
   public int getRowIdx()  {
      return  rowIdx;
   }
   public int getColumnIdx()  {
      return  colIdx;
   }
   public GridPosition getNeighbor(Direction dir)  {
      Objects.requireNonNull(dir, "dir");
      return  (new GridPosition(
         dir.getNewRowIdx(getRowIdx()),
         dir.getNewColIdx(getColumnIdx())));
   }
   public GridPosition getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction dir)  {
      if(isEdgeForDirection(dir))  {
         return  null;
      }
      return  getNeighbor(dir);
   }
   public int getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction dir)  {
      GridPosition pos = getNeighborNullIfEdge(dir);
      return  ((pos == null) ? -1 : pos.getValue());
   }
   public static final int getRowCount()  {
      return  GRID.length;
   }
   public static final int getColumnCount()  {
      return  GRID[0].length;
   }
   public boolean isEdgeForDirection(Direction dir)  {
      Objects.requireNonNull(dir);
      switch(dir)  {
         case UP:    return isTopEdge();
         case DOWN:  return isBottomEdge();
         case LEFT:  return isLeftEdge();
         case RIGHT: return isRightEdge();
      }
      throw  new IllegalStateException(toString() + ", dir=" + dir);
   }
   public boolean isLeftEdge()  {
      return  (getColumnIdx() == 0);
   }
   public boolean isTopEdge()  {
      return  (getRowIdx() == 0);
   }
   public boolean isBottomEdge()  {
      return  (getRowIdx() == rowIdxMinus1);
   }
   public boolean isRightEdge()  {
      return  (getColumnIdx() == colIdxMinus1);
   }
   public String toString()  {
      return  "[" + getRowIdx() + "," + getColumnIdx() + "]=" + getValue();
   }
   public String getNineByNine()  {
      int[][] nineByNine = new int[3][3];

      //Middle row
         nineByNine[1][1] = getValue();
         nineByNine[1][0] = getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
         nineByNine[1][2] = getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);

      //Top
         GridPosition posUp = getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction.UP);
         if(posUp != null)  {
            nineByNine[0][0] = posUp.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
            nineByNine[0][1] = posUp.getValue();
            nineByNine[0][2] = posUp.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);
         }

      //Bottom
         GridPosition posDown = getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction.DOWN);
         if(posDown != null)  {
            nineByNine[2][0] = posDown.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
            nineByNine[2][1] = posDown.getValue();
            nineByNine[2][2] = posDown.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);
         }

      String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
      return  "Middle position in 9x9 grid is *this*: " + toString() + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[0]) + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[1]) + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[2]);
   }
}
```

Here's a demo usage:

```
public class GridPosDemo  {
   private static final int[][] GRID = new int[][] {

   //mega grid goes here...

   };

   private static final GridPosition GRID_HOLDER = new GridPosition(GRID);

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      GridPosition pos = new GridPosition(0, 0);
      System.out.println("start: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.LEFT);
      System.out.println("left:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.UP);
      System.out.println("up:    " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.UP);
      System.out.println("up:    " + pos);

      System.out.println(pos.getNineByNine());
   }

}
```

Output

```
[C:\java_code\]java GridPosDemo
start: [0,0]=1
right: [0,1]=1
right: [0,2]=1
down:  [1,2]=1
down:  [2,2]=1
right: [2,3]=1
down:  [3,3]=0
left:  [3,2]=1
up:    [2,2]=1
up:    [1,2]=1
Middle position in 9x9 grid is *this*: [1,2]=1
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
```

In order to use this for traversing the correct path through a maze, this needs "collision detection" added to it (so it doesn't go through walls), in addition to something to keep track of where you've been (so you don't end up back at the start-position). Such as with some `getNeighborIfNotWall(Direction)` and `isWallToLeft()` functions.

Putting aside the maze-question, I would do the following before considering these classes complete:

- Make the array-type generic, instead of ints
- Add error checking, as documented in the code
- Re-design how you set the grid.
- Add diagonal directions: `UP_LEFT`, `UP_RIGHT`, `DOWN_LEFT`, `DOWN_RIGHT`
- Add the ability to move multiple steps in one direction: `getNeighbor(3, Direction.DOWN)`

Here's the entire source-code file, containing all of the above (including the mega-maze grid):

```
   //Needed only by GridPosition
   import  java.util.Arrays;
   import  java.util.Objects;

enum Direction {
   UP(-1, 0),
   DOWN(1, 0),
   LEFT(0, -1),
   RIGHT(0, 1);
//config
   private final int rowSteps;
   private final int colSteps;
   private Direction(int rowSteps, int colSteps)  {
      this.rowSteps = rowSteps;
      this.colSteps = colSteps;
   }
   public int getNewRowIdx(int currentRowIdx)  {
      return  (currentRowIdx + getRowSteps());
   }
   public int getNewColIdx(int currentColIdx)  {
      return  (currentColIdx + getColSteps());
   }
   public int getRowSteps()  {
      return  rowSteps;
   }
   public int getColSteps()  {
      return  colSteps;
   }
};

class GridPosition  {
//config
   private static int[][] GRID;
   private final int rowIdx;
   private final int colIdx;
//internal
   private final int rowIdxMinus1;
   private final int colIdxMinus1;
   public GridPosition(int[][] GRID)  {
      if(this.GRID != null)  {
         throw  new IllegalStateException("Grid already set. Use x/y constructor.");
      }
      GridPosition.GRID = GRID;

      //TODO: Crash if null or empty, or sub-arrays null or empty, or unequal lengths, or contain anything but 0 or -1.

      rowIdx = -1;
      colIdx = -1;
      rowIdxMinus1 = -1;
      colIdxMinus1 = -1;
   }
   public GridPosition(int rowIdx, int colIdx)  {
      if(GridPosition.GRID == null)  {
         throw  new IllegalStateException("Must set grid with: new GridPosition(int[][]).");
      }

      if(rowIdx < 0  ||  rowIdx >= GridPosition.getRowCount())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("rowIdx (" + rowIdx + ") is invalid.");
      }
      if(colIdx < 0  ||  colIdx >= GridPosition.getColumnCount())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("colIdx (" + colIdx + ") is invalid.");
      }

      this.rowIdx = rowIdx;
      this.colIdx = colIdx;
      rowIdxMinus1 = (rowIdx - 1);
      colIdxMinus1 = (colIdx - 1);
   }
   public int getValue()  {
      return  GridPosition.GRID[getRowIdx()][getColumnIdx()];
   }
   public int getRowIdx()  {
      return  rowIdx;
   }
   public int getColumnIdx()  {
      return  colIdx;
   }
   public GridPosition getNeighbor(Direction dir)  {
      Objects.requireNonNull(dir, "dir");
      return  (new GridPosition(
         dir.getNewRowIdx(getRowIdx()),
         dir.getNewColIdx(getColumnIdx())));
   }
   public GridPosition getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction dir)  {
      if(isEdgeForDirection(dir))  {
         return  null;
      }
      return  getNeighbor(dir);
   }
   public int getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction dir)  {
      GridPosition pos = getNeighborNullIfEdge(dir);
      return  ((pos == null) ? -1 : pos.getValue());
   }
   public static final int getRowCount()  {
      return  GRID.length;
   }
   public static final int getColumnCount()  {
      return  GRID[0].length;
   }
   public boolean isEdgeForDirection(Direction dir)  {
      Objects.requireNonNull(dir);
      switch(dir)  {
         case UP:    return isTopEdge();
         case DOWN:  return isBottomEdge();
         case LEFT:  return isLeftEdge();
         case RIGHT: return isRightEdge();
      }
      throw  new IllegalStateException(toString() + ", dir=" + dir);
   }
   public boolean isLeftEdge()  {
      return  (getColumnIdx() == 0);
   }
   public boolean isTopEdge()  {
      return  (getRowIdx() == 0);
   }
   public boolean isBottomEdge()  {
      return  (getRowIdx() == rowIdxMinus1);
   }
   public boolean isRightEdge()  {
      return  (getColumnIdx() == colIdxMinus1);
   }
   public String toString()  {
      return  "[" + getRowIdx() + "," + getColumnIdx() + "]=" + getValue();
   }
   public String getNineByNine()  {
      int[][] nineByNine = new int[3][3];

      //Middle row
         nineByNine[1][1] = getValue();
         nineByNine[1][0] = getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
         nineByNine[1][2] = getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);

      //Top
         GridPosition posUp = getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction.UP);
         if(posUp != null)  {
            nineByNine[0][0] = posUp.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
            nineByNine[0][1] = posUp.getValue();
            nineByNine[0][2] = posUp.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);
         }

      //Bottom
         GridPosition posDown = getNeighborNullIfEdge(Direction.DOWN);
         if(posDown != null)  {
            nineByNine[2][0] = posDown.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.LEFT);
            nineByNine[2][1] = posDown.getValue();
            nineByNine[2][2] = posDown.getNeighborValueNeg1IfEdge(Direction.RIGHT);
         }

      String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
      return  "Middle position in 9x9 grid is *this*: " + toString() + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[0]) + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[1]) + sLS +
         Arrays.toString(nineByNine[2]);
   }
}
public class GridPosDemo  {
   private static final int[][] GRID = new int[][] {
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};
   private static final GridPosition GRID_HOLDER = new GridPosition(GRID);

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      GridPosition pos = new GridPosition(0, 0);
      System.out.println("start: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT);
      System.out.println("right: " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.DOWN);
      System.out.println("down:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.LEFT);
      System.out.println("left:  " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.UP);
      System.out.println("up:    " + pos);

      pos = pos.getNeighbor(Direction.UP);
      System.out.println("up:    " + pos);

      System.out.println(pos.getNineByNine());
   }

}
```

Comment: Wow, and you solved it, by SO's account, in no time at all.  Well done you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer: Can I answer my own question? Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I think it would've been way better if you would just link to your answer. Furthermore, since the OP already said that he was intrigued by the question I'd put my money on that he has read the thing you posted here before. So maybe even a link would not have been necessary. Lastly, only the first part (with the enum) is (kind of) an answer to the question.